# Cron job in centos

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have few more doubt in crontab jobs

My scenario: I have put two cron jobs at 23 Hrs every day 1 job is move files to another directory & the 2nd job is upload this file to ftp server.

1. How to get last ran time cron job & last run result( if succeeded or failed  )details in centos ?
2. How to view at present running cron job  in centos ? ( example : 1st job starting at 23 Hrs  & the 2nd job starting at 23:30 Hrs and ending after 5 mins { assuming 1st cron job should be completed after 30mins , I want to view this job running details in live.(30 mints duration ) })

Log or live view

Note: Running as root user privilege.

Thanks
G Dhamu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can watch the logs of jobs that were ran by cron under `/var/log/cron` (default location)
2. You cannot have a "live view" since you're not the one who's running it... What you *can* do, is tail cron-log or have your program write its output to a different log and open a screen that tails it.

Answer (score 0):

How to upgrade apache 2.4.6 to 2.4.16 on CentOS -7..
‪#‎cat‬ /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core))